# Get from dao and insert in new thread with RxJava

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin

I have a problem. I want in new thread add my insert method from my dao. But I cant to use subscribe method. I have been got an error message. Because my Note class doesnt implements Observable interface.

My NoteRepository class

```
public class NoteRepository {

    private NoteDao noteDao;
    private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;

    public NoteRepository(Application application) {
        NoteDatabase database = NoteDatabase.getInstance(application);
        noteDao = database.noteDao();

        allNotes = noteDao.getAllNotes();
    }

    public Observable<Note> insert(Note note) {
        return Observable.fromIterable(allNotes.getValue())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }

    public Observable<Note> update(Note note) {
        
    }

    public Observable<Note> delete(Note note) {

    }

    public void deleteAllNotes() {

    }

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }
}
```

My NoteDao interface

```
    @Dao
    public interface NoteDao {
    
        @Insert
        Observable<Note> insert(Note note);
    
        @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
        Observable<Note> update(Note note);
    
        @Delete
        void delete(Note note);
    
        @Query("DELETE FROM note_table")
        void deleteAllNotes();
    
        @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table ORDER BY priority DESC")
        LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning a `Completable` and update the `insert` method to add the `Note`:

```
public Completable insert(Note note) {
    return Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
          noteDao.getAllNotes();
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

I also suggest using `Schedulers.io` in `subscribeOn`. It's similar to `newThread` except `io` recycles threads.

In `NoteDao`. You don't need to return `Observable<Note>` from the `insert` or `update`  methods. You already have the note from passing it in as a parameter:

```
    @Insert
    void insert(Note note);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void update(Note note);
```

Comment: You’re welcome. If you’re happy with the answer can you accept it please.